# How can I slide a button/textbox or any control in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to simply animate a text-box such that it fades in and also moves to the left (or any x/y position). How can I achieve that?

Also will it matter if it's inside a Grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sketchy method i just wrote for fading in any kind of `UIElement`:

```
    public static void FadeIn(UIElement element, int xOffset, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        Transform tempTrans = element.RenderTransform;
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform(xOffset, 0);
        TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
        if (tempTrans != null) group.Children.Add(tempTrans);
        group.Children.Add(trans);

        DoubleAnimation animTranslate = new DoubleAnimation(0, (Duration)duration);
        animTranslate.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
        DoubleAnimation animFadeIn = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, (Duration)duration) { FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop };
        animTranslate.Completed += delegate
        {
            element.RenderTransform = tempTrans;
        };

        element.RenderTransform = trans;
        element.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animFadeIn);
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animTranslate);
    }
```

If some of the workings are not clear feel free to ask.

Comment: hey, thanks that helps. Can you tell me why did you use EasingFunction (and specifically why CubicEase) ?

Comment: Just so that the controls don't stop so appruptly, thought it just looks more fluent and nicer that way.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about the cubic ease, used that because i think it constitutes a nice compromise between initial movement speed and decay softness/duration. Compare the graphs on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751.aspx

Comment: @ShahidMZubair: Just reverse the order of the 0 and 1 in the `DoubleAnimation` animating the opacity.