# In WPF 4.0, How can I open the row details of a datagrid gradually?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How can I make the row details open (and close) gradually, preferably without using Blend?

The reason I want this is that I have a screen where elements move, fade in and out etc using [transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989008/how-can-i-slide-a-button-textbox-or-any-control-in-wpf), and i want the row details action to be consistent with all other actions.

An additional action I would like to animate is hiding (and un-hiding) of datagrid columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind that the animation squashes the contents rather than sliding them in then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587374/animating-wpf-datagrid-row-details/5588022#5588022) might be helpful.